# How to Compare Oracle Table with Hive Table using shell script

Tags: shell, hive, bigdata

I'm not understanding on how to compare Oracle table and a Hive table using shell script.

In this I need to compare all the column details like column name, datatype and size. If there is/are any unmatched columns then those need to printed.

Can any one please help me on this.

Thanks,
Sujit

Comment: Probably not without seeing them.

Comment: Due to client constraints I can not share the details here. Let us consider oracle table "OTable" has 10 columns col1,col2....col10 and hive table "HTable" has 12 columns col1,col2......colTen,col11,col12. In this case Number of columns are different and col10 and colTen are different.